# 2 symbols arguments for tools in Python

Tags: python

How to create arguments with 2 symbols

i know how to create -t, -u, -h but how to create arguments with 2 symbols like -db, -ab, etc

here is the code i create

```
opts, _ = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "t:u:h[db]", ["target=", "url=", 'help'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The second and third arguments to `getopt` are the short options and the long options.  An option you specify in the short options string can only be one character long.  The long options can be longer, but they must be specified in the input with a prefix of `--`.  So you could define an option `--db`, but not an option `-db`.

For the sake of completeness, I should note that you don't have to use `getopt`.  You can parse the command line with your own software if you want.  If you did that, you could certainly support two-letter options.  It would just be more development work.